# Error 2465 in MS Access when running a VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-access

Read through a few of the previously asked posts about this error but still cannot understand it.

The error text is "Run-time error '2465' CASREP reporting tool can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression

I have a form to assign parts to certain supply reports. We have a form where users can manually hyperlink the parts to the request if they fall in the cracks. There is a check box feature, followed by the use of an "Assign" button to achieve this.

Every time a box is checked and a user selects "Assign" the error pops up. The string of code that pops up with the bug is as follows:

```
    strSQL_del = "DELETE FROM [tbl_Temp_Assign] " & _
    "WHERE [jcn_cd]= '" & Forms![Parts: Assign Unit].[tblTemp_Assign subform1].Form.[jcn.cd] & "' 
     AND [CASREP #] = '" & strCASREP & "' AND [doc_num_cd] = '" & Forms![Parts: Assign Unit].[tblTemp_Assign subform1].Form.[doc_num_cd] & "' 
     AND [last_updated_dte] = #" & Forms![Parts: Assign Unit].[tblTemp_Assign subform1].Form.[last_updated_dte] & "# 
     AND [PMOMsgDte] = #" & Forms![Parts: Assign Unit].[tblTemp_Assign Unit].Form.[PMOMsgDte] & "#" 'Intentionally left off AssignDte
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm lost on what is wrong.

Comment: What is the text of the error message?

Comment: The error text is "Run-time error '2465'

CASREP reporting tool can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression @TimWilliams

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake on my end, there is no space there in the actual code itself @HansUp

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the SQL string concatenation, but that string is quite long, it's hard to say if you have a space between `'` and the first `AND` condition. Also, after the first continuation character `_`, is all that a single line?

Anyway, I would strongly advise to setup a delete query where you pass the form values as parameters and in VBA you just execute the query. It will be easier to update later on if needed.

The query:

```sql
PARAMETERS [prmTextField] Text (50), [prmDateField] DateTime, [prmNumberField] Long;
DELETE *
FROM T
WHERE T.TextField = [prmTextField]
  AND T.DateField = [prmDateField]
  AND T.NumberField = [prmNumberField];
```

Then, in VBA just execute the query.

```vb
With CurrentDb().QueryDefs("QueryName")
    .Parameters("[prmTextField]").Value = '[Value from Form (text)]
    .Parameters("[prmDateField]").Value = '[Value from Form (date)]
    .Parameters("[prmNumberField]").Value = '[Value from Form (number)]
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With
```

By the way, do you really need to pass all those parameters to delete a record? Usually, just the record id is needed.

Comment: I'm not sure. I just begun working on this tool today so this is my first time seeing what you are seeing as well. 

```    strSQL_del = "DELETE FROM [tbl_Temp_Assign] " & _ 
is a single line and the rest is all a single line. I just broke it up for readability.